# Boost causes an invalid block while overloading new/delete operators

Tags: c++, boost, overloading, new-operator

I have a problem which appears to a be an invalid memory block that happens during a Boost call to `Boost:runtime:cla::parser::~parser`. When that global delete is called on that object, C++ asserts on the memory block as an invalid:

```
dbgdel.cpp(52):

/* verify block type */
_ASSERTE(_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse));
```

An investigation I did revealed that the problem happened because of a global overloading of the new/delete operators. Those overloadings are placed in a separate DLL. I discovered that the problem happens only when that DLL is compiled in RELEASE while the main application is compiled in DEBUG.

So I thought that the Release/Debug build flavors might have created a problem like this in Boost/CRT when overloading new/delete operators. So I then tried to explicitly call to _malloc_dbg and _free_dbg withing the overloading functions even in release mode, but it didn't solve the invalid heap block problem.

Any idea what the root cause of the problem is? is that situation solvable?

I should stress that the problem began only when I started to use Boost. Before that CRT never complained about any invalid memory block. So could it be an internal Boost bug?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> I discovered that the problem happens only when that DLL is compiled in RELEASE while the main application is compiled in DEBUG

In general you cannot mix modules that use the release CRT with the debug CRT if memory allocation from one type of runtime is freed by the other runtime (there might be other issues, but memory allocation problems seem to crop up the most).

The solution is to use modules that are built against the debug runtime with each other, and modules that are built against the release runtime with each other - don't mix the two.

Microsoft's explanation can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235460.aspx

> because each copy of the CRT library has its own heap manager, allocating memory in one CRT library and passing the pointer across a DLL boundary to be freed by a different copy of the CRT library is a potential cause for heap corruption.

Comment: Michael, Thanks for the answer. However, since both new/delete are done in the same RELEASE DLL, I don't understand how that mixture really happens. The same memory block that was allocated in the DLL is also freed by the same DLL because of the new/delete overloading which implmented in the same DLL. Before using Boost, CRT never complained about that though I used its libraries extensively. Only with Boost it happens and on that specific parser object. That leaves me clueless...

Comment: @user555746: that's interesting...  and not what I would expect on first thought. Is there a reasonably small repro case using a standard boost download?

Comment: All what I do is as follows:
1. Create an EXE with standard Boost library to implement aunit test using Boost's API - you can leave the unit test empty
2. Create a simple DLL and create two exported functions that act as new/delete and simply do malloc/free inside
3. Within the EXE overload the new/delete globally and call the exported functions from the DLL to delegate the call
4. Run the application, and during CRT teardown you should get the ASSERT above for the boost::runtime::cla::parser::~parser which is probably one of the internal classes Boost is using for the unit test framework

Comment: You can add the BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE to create the empty test case and the following form of overloading: 
inline void* operator new(size_t size) 
{ return exported_new(size); } inline void operator delete(void* pUserData) { return exported_delete(pUserData); }

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response (holidays and all). I'm unable to repro your problem using the steps above. I tried my best to follow them correctly, but might be missing something. I'm using VS2008 and Boost 1.44 downloaded from boostpro.com. The .exe links to the static boost lib: `libboost_unit_test_framework-vc90-mt-gd-1_44.lib` (pre-built by BoostPro - not built myself). So it's a boost library compiled for debug mode and linking to the debug CRT.  The DLL that has the functions called by the `new`/`delete` overloads is compiled for release and links to the non-debug runtime DLL.